# Azure functions imperative binding for javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Function that writes to a blob.
Specifically, I need the path I save to, to be comprised of the UTC date (for example yy/MM/dd/hh:mm:ss). In my case, I am using function.json to achieve this: `{
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "myContainer/{datetime:yyyy}/{datetime:MM}/{datetime:dd}/{datetime:hh}-{datetime:mm}-{datetime:ss}",
      "connection": "smth_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }`

However, I want more flexibility with it. I need the time to be UTC (which time does it use by default?). The {datetime:XXXX} is not documented anywhere and I found it on another stackoverflow question, but for the sake of the general need, how would I achieve more flexibility with the output filename when using javascript for the Azure Function?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is the document about `DateTime` binding, the DateTime resolves to DateTime.UtcNow, so yes the time is UTC. For more information you could refer to this doc:[Current time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#current-time).

Then is about flexibility, you need provide more information, you want to bind it at runtime, provide by http request or other way you want. Cause you are using nodejs, there are many limits.

Comment: I found out it was indeed UTC, but thank you for that. Flexibility-wise, I currently don't have something specific that I need, but in general it would be nice to be able to use variables within the code for that. My understanding is that we can't.

Comment: For now if you want to use binding to implement it, this is impossible, cause you could only define the function.json file to do it or use the storage sdk to do it. Another way if your function is http one you could use pass json data to bind the blob info to function.json.

Comment: I still don't fully understand your second explanation. Say I want to name the file some random string that is created in the code. Is this possible? How could I otherwise have more control of the filename?

Comment: For now,if you want to do it in function.json you could try `rand-guid`however  if you want  a random file name in the code you could use the storage sdk   then use the blob client to do it. Also if you are using http trigger function, you could pass file name i the request body. All binding expression you could refer to this doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns